# who define the integer type range in c language

Tags: c, gcc

I learned that in x86_64 platform, the `int` range is from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

In [c99](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), the min value of  `int max` is `+32767`:

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
> Maximum value for an object of type int
> INT_MAX +32767

In [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/limits_002eh.html), it references [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html):

> {INT_MAX} Maximum value for an object of type int.
> [CX] [Option Start] Minimum Acceptable Value: 2 147 483 647

---

### my question

There are multiple documents defining the range of `int`, they do not contradict each other, but who **really defines the final int max value** on a specific platform like x86_64?

I guess it is one of the following, but I do not know which one:

- the compiler, e.g. gcc/llvm
- glibc
- cpu company, e.g. intel

Comment: Related: [Implementation-defined behavior in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973073/implementation-defined-behavior-in-c)

Comment: Also [Is there a complete list of Implementation-Defined behavior in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225757/is-there-a-complete-list-of-implementation-defined-behavior-in-c)

Comment: it is the compilers choice, but the number of bits for int should be something natural for the CPU. ie int being 27 bits would be very odd. But, for example long long is different on 64 bit MSVCC vs 64 bit gcc

Comment: @pm100 so it is compile defined ?  how can i find the define behavior in gcc ,i cannot find this relative document

Comment: the best way to find out is to use sizeof and print the result. If you need to control the size then use the defined size types defined in stdint.h (int8_t, int16_ ,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of integer types is determined, on many platforms, by the target ABI (Application Binary Interface). The ABI is defined usually by the operating system and/or compiler used. Programs compiled with the same ABI can often interoperate, even if they are compiled by different compilers.

For example, on many Intel-based Linux and UNIX machines, the [System V ABI](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) determines the sizes of the fundamental C types per processor; there are different definitions for x86 and x86-64, for example, but they will be consistent across all systems that use that ABI. Compilers targeting Intel Linux machines will typically use the System V ABI, so you get the same `int` no matter which compiler you use. However, Microsoft operating systems will use a different ABI (actually, several, depending on how you look), which defines the fundamental types differently.

Modern desktop systems almost always provide 4-byte ints. However, embedded systems will often provide smaller ints; the Arduino AVR platform, for example, defines `int` as a 16-bit type. This is again dependent on the compiler and processor (no OS in this case).

So, the short answer is that "it depends". Your compiler (in some specific configuration) will ultimately be responsible for translating `int` into a machine type, so in some sense your compiler is the ultimate source of truth. But the compiler's decision might be informed by an existing ABI standard, by the standards of the OS, the processor, or just existing convention.

Comment: [gcc reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Range-of-Type.html) >Suppose you need to store an integer value which can range from zero to one million. Which is the smallest type you can use? There is no general rule; it depends on the C compiler and target machine

Comment: [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/commit/b20e47cb14ec8edccab7c722743a731e67280702?diff=unified#diff-60a0873345e522f21ac3aa7b85bfa07c5e11f70e0a12225806431972e479db04R118)i think your answer is right,it depend  compiler and target machine. the gcc choice use `limit.h` ,and the `limit.h` will be difference in  target machine

Answer (score 3):

As far as C is concerned, it's up the compiler.

---

Of the constants in limits.h, the C17 standard says

> 5.2.4.2.1.1 [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign. [...]

The term "implementation" is used throughout to refer to the C compiler and associated libraries.

> 5. An implementation translates C source files and executes C programs in two data-processing-system environments, which will be called the *translation environment* and the *execution environment* in this International Standard. Their characteristics define and constrain the results of executing
> conforming C programs constructed according to the syntactic and semantic rules for conforming implementations.

It is not directly based on the hardware, as your question presumes. For example, Microsoft's C compiler for Windows for the x86-64 uses a 32-bit `long`, but my `gcc` has a 64-bit `long` for Linux on the same hardware.

Answer (score 1):

> who really define the final int max value in specific platform like x86_64?

The compiler defines the final int max value.

The value is not necessary specific to platform, you can compile code for x86_84 architecture using a compiler with an int with 16-bits, or with 64-bits, or any bits. C language is an *abstraction*, the compiler translates that abstraction to machine code.

Answer (score 1):

This is so called "data model" which is defined by ABI which is realized by compiler and of course all libraries (including glibc which you mentioned) comply with it.
The notation is "C" - for char, "S" - for short, "I" - for int, "L" - for long and "P" - for pointer.
So, 32bit ABI data model is C8S16I32L32P32. To get short and more nice-looking string we skip prefixes notating standard (more like - common or traditional, because C standard doesn't define exact sizes for types) sizes and move the size to the end. So we get ILP32, what means that int, long and pointer are 32 bits long (while char is left 8-bit and short is 16-bit long).
For x86_64 ABI it is LP64 (I suppose you already can form full notation of this data model and see what size is int on this ABI).
And yes, Windows world is different - it's 64-bit data model is LLP64. That means that 64-bit long are only long long and pointer types (long is still 32-bit long).

Comment: do you have link about this to  describe  "ABI data model" ? i can not search for it

Comment: The first article I've read on this topic (and favorite of mine) is [64-Bit Programming Models: Why LP64?](https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html)
Data model is mentioned in [System V Application Binary Interface](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf)

Comment: Also you can read [64-bit data models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) (notice the SILP64 data model)